# How to display the UIActionSheet view from above Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet, tabbarcontroller

I need to display the action sheet above the Tab Bar controller. I mean, I would be able to see the Tab Bar controller even the action sheet view is in visible mode.

So, Please suggest how to view from above the Tab Bar controller. Is it possible.

secondly, How to change the back ground color of action sheet and cancel button back ground colour.

Please help me

Thank You,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To display an action sheet from a tab bar, you can call the following within the view controller that is presenting it:
`[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];`

Note that the references explicitly state that action sheets cannot be styled. Nor is there anyway that I know of to make an action sheet appear on top of a tab bar. If you wish to step around the established interface guidelines in the manner you stated, you will probably have to create a custom view.

**edit**: The reason that the action sheet normally obscures the tab bar is that it is intended to be modal: either the user chooses an action, or they cancel. Either way, they shouldn't navigate away before making the choice, which your desired layout would imply.