# ABPersonViewController delete button warning

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uiactionsheet, abpersonviewcontroller

I have an iPhone application that I use the ABPersonViewController and I allow delete.

The thing is that the application is a TabBar application and when i use the regular delete method I get this warning:

> Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].

the problem is that when I try to press on the "Cancel" of the delete, it does not work!
I want the action sheet to pop up from the TabBar, How do I do that?

this is the code:

```
if ([personController respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsDeletion:)])
    [personController setAllowsDeletion:YES]; //CAN CAUSE THE APPLICATION TO BE DENIED FROM THE APP-STORE
```

Comment: How do you call setAllowsDeletion without getting compile error?

Answer (score 1):

To display an action sheet from a tab bar, you can call the following within the view controller that is presenting it: `[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];`

This answer is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774270/how-to-display-the-uiactionsheet-view-from-above-tab-bar-controller) post.

Comment: thank you for your time, but this answer is no good for me, i know all about the function showfromtabbar, but the problem is that i dont call the action sheet. i just allow delete on the ABPersonViewController, and when the user press on the delete button there the action sheet pop's up, this is apple's code... not mine.

Comment: Important: Person view controllers must be used with a navigation controller in order to function properly. This was specified in the class reference of apple documentation. What i can guess is, the cancel button is visible but is clipped by the tab bar present at the bottom, which is refraining it from receiving touches?!

Comment: ok.... you are right, when i press on the top of the cancel button it is working and if i press on the bottom of the button it does not.

so now i have a new question, how do i properly configure this?
i have a TabBar application and in the nib file i added the tabbar buttons and called the other nib's....

Comment: You could always display it modally.