# Add Actionsheet in UITabbarcontroller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I created UITabbar in UIViewController. Then i added a UIActionSheet to it but when the actionsheet appeared, when top part of button "Cancel" is clicked, it works, but when I click the bottom part of "Cancel", there's no response. I used this code to add the actionsheet:

```
actionSheetDelete = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to continue?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Item(s)" otherButtonTitles:nil];
actionSheetDelete.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[actionSheetDelete showInView:self.view];
[actionSheetDelete release];
```

When i click on action sheet, i always show this alarm in console:

```
Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the UIActionSheet view from above Tab Bar Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774270/how-to-display-the-uiactionsheet-view-from-above-tab-bar-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could show it in the view of the UITabBarController:

```
actionSheetDelete = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to continue?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Item(s)" otherButtonTitles:nil];
actionSheetDelete.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[actionSheetDelete showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
[actionSheetDelete release];
```

Alternatively, a slightly more robust version might be:

```
[actionSheetDelete showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Comment: `showFromTabBar` of `UIActionSheet` is designed to work with `UITabbar`

Comment: Yes, although I think I prefer the `showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` approach anyhow.  This way my view controller doesn't have to know if it is being presented in a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: This is not the proper way...Check out my answer.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your goal.  Personally I don't like to write view controller code that depends on how the view controller is presented.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[actionSheetDelete showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Comment: I tried your code but it show errr:Assertion failure in -[UIActionSheet _presentSheetFromView:above:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIActionSheet.m:1778
2013-08-12 14:34:37.905 Cloudstringers[4253:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show the action sheet from the view itself. This cannot be done considering you have the UITabBarController inside the view already. Therefore, you have to set it from the tab bar when it is shown. This will ensure that the buttons are not loaded underneath the view of the tab bar, and allow the availability of all the actions associated with the tab bar.

Therefore, you should use

```
[actionSheetDelete showFromTabBar:];
```

so that the tab bar is the initial location of where the action sheet is shown
Hope this helps!